# Automating Cognos Build in Transformer

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

All of a sudden, scheduled tasks that update the Cognos Cubes are getting failed. When I try to run it manually from the CMD it is getting executed successfully. But, when I try to create a bat file and run the below script nothing is happening. Could someone look into this and let me know if anything is wrong.

@echo on
C:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\cognos\c10\bin"
Cogtr.exe -n2 -m "C:\Cognos\cube models\test.mdl"

Comment: 1. Post the actual error. 2. Have you checked the transformer logs? 3. Is the scheduler running under an appropriate windows account? 4. What ype of scheduler is it - windows? 5. When you run the script above, surely something happens, i.e. a black box DOS temporarily appears. Please be more specific and do some further troubleshooting and checking of various logs.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your formatting got awry when posting to the forum, but in general it looks ok. 

When you say “nothing happens” — there might be a cogtr process in background you don't see.

You're running with n2 command line syntax, making Transformer run “background”
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cogtr.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_cogtr_id13215n_option.html

Check Task Manager to see if that's the case. You can change the line to just -n to see a bit more action )